# PHP variables and media queries

Tags: php, css, variables, media-queries

So I'm trying to bend my mind around a little problem I have and I hope there are som clever mind around here.

I generate seven (7) circles which gets their width and height values from a PHP variable where the max value is 100 and then set these values with inline CSS in pixels.

Unfortunatly a 100 pixel circle is way too small on the desktop version (or should I say in a Media Query starting at around 1200px). So I multiply the input by 4 by using calc() in CSS.

On the other hand a 400px circle is too big for a mobile, so I would only like to multiply the input by 2 there, but then the combination of inline CSS, a PHP variable and media queries is a no go, as far as I know.

So I'm looking for a solution where I can change the variable number I multiply the width and height with based on media queries.

One solution that feels like a hack is device detection. With that I can run a if/else and do this. A another solution I have been thinking about is wether I can create the circles as percentages and not in pixels and then set max-width and max-height to different values in the media queries, but when I tried I got a problem with circles getting ellipse shapes when scaling the browser window. The best solution would be to change the variable it multiplies with based on screen size. Is this a JS job? Or could I maybe generate a SVG on the fly.

My problem with the device detection solution at the moment is basicly that if I resize my browser window on a desktop machine it still multiplies by 4 so my positioning of the circles looks like a mess.

This makes up my structure for the circles. There are 7 of them and a container around. The key is the value I multiply by (4). Can that possibly be changed based on media queries?

```
<div class="circle-1" style="
   width: calc(<?php echo $my_variable; ?>px * 4); 
   height: calc(<?php echo $my_variable; ?>px * 4);">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to do?  It's not entirely clear.  Code would be extremely helpful

Comment: Use %'s from the get go.

Comment: Using different CSS classes and swapping them in and out with JS based on browser dimensions might be one way.

A further caveat is that AFAIK calc() won't work on some, if not all, versions of Safari. It will cause the page to crash.